# CSS - I am stuck on a css animation coding issue on codepen

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

http://codepen.io/jayclark/pen/wDety

I would like to make the green bar stay where it is when it gets to the full circle rather than repeating the animation over and over again. If anyone could help me I would much appreciate it. All of the necessary code is on the codepen file.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

to

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

and remove

```
border-left-color: transparent;
border-top-color: transparent;
```

from `.timer-l, .timer-r`

[**DEMO here.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BfHGw)

Comment: Thanks that does what I asked but is there any way to have it so the green bar isn't jumpy, so it loads up fluently from small to big?